# Sonatype nexus: unable to use http proxy after update from 2.2 to 2.10.0-02

Tags: http, proxy, nexus, sonatype

We use sonatype nexus on Windows Server 2008 R2. To be able to access external repositories we use an corporate http proxy server. Therefore we entered in `Nexus GUI->Server` the values "proxy host", "proxy port", "username" and "password". After migration from Nexus 2.2 to 2.10.0-02 the nexus server is not able to access external repositories.

If now I go to Nexus GUI-> `Repositories->Central->Browse Remote->Refresh` the remote repository is not visible. The wrapper.log contains following log entries (original data was replaced by `<proxyhost>:<proxyport> and <proxyuser>`):

```
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl - <proxyhost>:<proxyport> proxy authentication setup for remote storage with username '<proxyuser>'
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl - http proxy setup with host '<proxyhost>'
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.rrb.MavenRepositoryReader - remotePath=
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.rrb.MavenRepositoryReader - Requesting: GET http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/?delimiter=/ HTTP/1.1
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl$ManagedClientConnectionManager - Connection request: [route: {}->http://<proxyhost>:<proxyport>->http://repo1.maven.org:80][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 2 of 200]
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl$ManagedClientConnectionManager - Connection leased: [id: 25][route: {}->http://<proxyhost>:<proxyport>->http://repo1.maven.org:80][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 2 of 200]
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.rrb.MavenRepositoryReader - Status code: 407
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl$ManagedClientConnectionManager - Connection [id: 25][route: {}->http://<proxyhost>:<proxyport>->http://repo1.maven.org:80] can be kept alive for 30.0 seconds
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 DEBUG [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.apachehttpclient.Hc4ProviderImpl$ManagedClientConnectionManager - Connection released: [id: 25][route: {}->http://<proxyhost>:<proxyport>->http://repo1.maven.org:80][total kept alive: 1; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 2 of 200]
| 2014-11-25 08:55:25 TRACE [qtp949677682-69] - org.sonatype.nexus.plugins.rrb.MavenRepositoryReader - <HEAD><TITLE>Proxy Authorization Required</TITLE></HEAD>
| <BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Proxy Authorization Required</H1><HR>
| <FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
| Description: Authorization is required for access to this proxy</B></FONT>
| <HR>
| <!-- default "Proxy Authorization Required" response (407) -->
| </BODY>
```

Wireshark capture looks like this:

```
43  1.803445000 <nexus> <proxyhost> HTTP    278 GET http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/?delimiter=/ HTTP/1.1 
51  1.814045000 <nexus> <proxyhost> HTTP    278 GET http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/?delimiter=/ HTTP/1.1 
55  1.819731000 <proxyhost> <nexus> HTTP    1014    HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy Authorization Required  (text/html)
```

all GET requests doesn't have any authentication headers.
Why Nexus does not repeat the GET request with credentials after HTTP 407?

Does anyone have similar issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the proxy server might be configured to use NTLM authentication?  Try entering the "NT LAN Manager Domain" in the proxy authentication also.

Comment: Thank you, I entered the "NT LAN Manager Domain" and it works correctly now.